# Angular + socketio don't work?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, mean-stack

Currently I'm trying to implement a real-time content with socket.io and angular.js, and as far as I concern I did everything correct, but the real-time doesnt work. Maybe I miss out anything important.

I will write a scenario of how its supposed to work. Basically a user write a content and then post the value to the server. In home.html, the content supposed to be real time(I have put everything below including home.html).

Here's the code

server.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var path        = require('path');
var config      = require('./config');

// REAL TIME WORK
var http        = require('http').Server(app);
var io          = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

// log our request to our terminal
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Connect to our database using mongoose
mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Connection to a mongodb database has failed");
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to a database");
    }
});


// set our static files to a designated location
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api') (app, express, io);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// registered before your api routes.
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
});

http.listen(config.port, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("There's an error connecting the app to port" + config.port);
    } else {
        console.log("App is listening on port " + config.port);
    }
});
```

api.js

```
module.exports = function(app, express, io) {

    // creating our first router
    var apiRouter = express.Router();

    // signup a user
    var createStory = function(req, res) {

        var story = new Story({
            user: req.decoded.id,
            content: req.body.content
        });

        story.save(function(err) {

            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            io.emit('story', req.body.content);
            res.json({ message: 'Story has been created!'});

        });
    };

    apiRouter.route('/')

        .post(createStory)


        .get(function(req, res) {

            Story.find({ user: req.decoded.id }, function(err, story) {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                }

                res.json(story);
            });


        });
```

service.js

```
angular.module('storyService', [])


.factory('Story', function($http, $window) {

    // get all approach
    var storyFactory = {};

    var generateReq = function(method, url, data) {
            var req = {
              method: method,
              url: url,
              headers: {
                'x-access-token': $window.localStorage.getItem('token')
              },
              cache: false
            }

            if(method === 'POST') {
                req.data = data;
            }
            return req;
        };

    storyFactory.all = function() {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/'));
    };


    storyFactory.create = function(storyData) {
        return $http(generateReq('POST', '/api/', storyData));
    };

    storyFactory.getSingleStory = function(user_name, story_id) {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/' + user_name + '/' + story_id));
    };

    storyFactory.allStories = function() {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/all_stories'));
    };

    return storyFactory;

})


.factory('socketio', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        var socket = io.connect();
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])


.controller('StoryController', function(Story, $routeParams, $scope, socketio) {

    var vm = this;

    Story.all()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.stories = data;
    });


    Story.getSingleStory($routeParams.user_name, $routeParams.story_id)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.storyData = data;
    });

    vm.createStory = function() {


        vm.message = '';

        Story.create(vm.storyData) 
        .success(function(data) {


                // clear the form
                vm.storyData = {}
                vm.message = data.message;

                socketio.on('story', function () {
                    $scope.stories.push(data);
                });

            });
    };

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Diary</title>


    <base href="/">

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <!-- load bootstrap from CDN and custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.1/paper/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

    <!-- directives -->



    <!--controllers -->

    <script src="app/controllers/storyCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/storyService.js"></script>


    <!-- main Angular app files -->
    <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>


</head>


<body ng-app="userApp">


<main class="container">

    <!-- ANGULAR VIEWS -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</main>



</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="story in stories | reverse" >
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
                    <div>
                        <div class="mic-info">
                            {{ story.createdAt | date:'MMM d, yyyy' }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-text">
                        <h4>{{ story.content }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know its huge, the reason why I'm posting it all is because I don't want to miss out on anything.

I'm really new to this whole socket.io + angular.js, if you have any opinion that could teach me something about socket.io + angular.js that would mean alot to me :)

Comment: In your StoryController you're registering the event listener each time you create a new post, you should do that once (plus it would be registered after the first emit on the server). Also the controller seems to use a mix of the `controllerAs` syntax and `$scope`

Comment: Thank you for replying but could you elaborate this as an answer so that I could accept it and Im' still confuse of what to do right now.

Comment: I've commented as I'm not sure if it'll fix the problem. The first point I meant is that you only need to register the event listener `socketio.on('story', function(content){ // })` once, not each time you create a new story. Second, if you are using the `controllerAs` syntax then you should assign to `this` or `vm` in your case, not `$scope`

Comment: Should i invoke it inside or outside promise object? and about **this** don't worry about it, right now the problem is where to push the data and how to do it. Please help me :(

Comment: Is it okay if I show you the open source code and the website? so maybe you could point where did i do wrong

Comment: Sure, that would help

Comment: Thank you. This is the website https://user-testing2015.herokuapp.com and the source code https://github.com/kacak9229/user .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70634/discussion-between-jonnyynnoj-and-airsoftfreak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the comments.

1. An event listener `socketio.on(..)` only needs to be created once. It will receive all future events until it is removed. Also don't mix `vm` and `$scope`

   ```
   angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])


   .controller('StoryController', function(Story, $routeParams, socketio) {

       var vm = this;
       vm.stories = [];

       Story.all()
       .success(function(data) {
           vm.stories = data;
       });


       Story.getSingleStory($routeParams.user_name, $routeParams.story_id)
       .success(function(data) {
           vm.storyData = data;
       });

       vm.createStory = function() {
           vm.message = '';

           Story.create(vm.storyData) 
           .success(function(data) {
               // clear the form
               vm.storyData = {}
               vm.message = data.message;
           });
       };

       socketio.on('story', function (data) {
           vm.stories.push(data);
       });
   });
   ```

   Create the controller like `ng-controller="StoryController as StoryCtrl"` and repeat with `ng-repeat="story in StoryCtrl.stories"`
2. Your server side emit only responds with the post content when it seems it should return an object with at least `content` and `createdAt` properties

   ```
   // signup a user
   var createStory = function(req, res) {

       var story = new Story({
           user: req.decoded.id,
           content: req.body.content
       });

       story.save(function(err) {

           if(err) {
               res.send(err);
               return;
           }

           io.emit('story', {
               user: req.decoded.id,
               createdAt: new Date(),
               content: req.body.content
           });

           // you might be able to do instead
           // io.emit('story', story.toObject())

           res.json({ message: 'Story has been created!'});

       });
   };
   ```

Comment: it works but after the third try the real time data kinda stop its really weird. if you go to your account and try to post data and go to route '/allStories' the real time doesnt show up. Thank you again

Comment: I mean try to open 2 browser , 1 incognito and normal browser

Comment: I can't test, the code on your heroku hasn't changed

Comment: You can check it now, basically its still not real time and as well as the whenever you hit the third post , the data doesnt show up.

Comment: The `socket.on('story', ..)` is still in the wrong place so each time you create a story you add a new listener. Adding 2 stories creates 2 listeners and the story gets pushed to `stories` twice. `ng-repeat` then stops working as you have duplicate items. Your allStories route won't be real-time as there's no event listener there

Comment: Hey jonnyy I have a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447621/content-is-loading-everytime-i-refresh-the-page?noredirect=1 since you know most of my codes.