# content is loading everytime I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm developing a simple CRUD application with MEAN stack. So the scenario is a user post a data to the server and it will render the data in real-time. Everything works fine but whenever I refresh the page ,

It will sort of loads all the content, every time it tries to fetch the data. I guess this is a caching problem.

So what I want to achieve is, every time a user refresh the page or go to another link, the content will be there without waiting for split seconds.

Here's the link to test it on, try to refresh the page
https://user-testing2015.herokuapp.com/allStories

and the code

controller.js

```
// start our angular module and inject our dependecies
angular.module('storyCtrl', ['storyService'])


.controller('StoryController', function(Story, $routeParams, socketio) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.stories = [];

    Story.all()
    .success(function(data) {
        vm.stories = data;
    });


    Story.getSingleStory($routeParams.story_id)
    .success(function(data) {
        vm.storyData = data;
    });

    vm.createStory = function() {
        vm.message = '';

        Story.create(vm.storyData) 
        .success(function(data) {
            // clear the form
            vm.storyData = {}
            vm.message = data.message;
        });
    };

    socketio.on('story', function (data) {
        vm.stories.push(data);
    });
})


.controller('AllStoryController', function(Story, socketio) {

    var vm = this;

    Story.allStories()
    .success(function(data) {
        vm.stories = data;
    });

     socketio.on('story', function (data) {
        vm.stories.push(data);
    });

})
```

service.js

```
angular.module('storyService', [])


.factory('Story', function($http, $window) {

    // get all approach
    var storyFactory = {};

    var generateReq = function(method, url, data) {
            var req = {
              method: method,
              url: url,
              headers: {
                'x-access-token': $window.localStorage.getItem('token')
              },
              cache: false
            }

            if(method === 'POST') {
                req.data = data;
            }
            return req;
        };

    storyFactory.all = function() {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/'));
    };


    storyFactory.create = function(storyData) {
        return $http(generateReq('POST', '/api/', storyData));
    };

    storyFactory.getSingleStory = function(story_id) {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/' + story_id));
    };

    storyFactory.allStories = function() {
        return $http(generateReq('GET', '/api/all_stories'));
    };

    return storyFactory;

})


.factory('socketio', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        var socket = io.connect();
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

api.js (both find all object and single object)

```
apiRouter.get('/all_stories', function(req, res) {

            Story.find({} , function(err, stories) {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                }

                res.json(stories);
            });
        });


apiRouter.get('/:story_id', function(req, res) {

        Story.findById(req.params.story_id, function(err, story) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            res.json(story);
        });
    });
```

For api.js whenever I refresh the page for '/all_stories' or go to a '/:story_id' it will load the data for split seconds.

allStories.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">


    </div>

    <!-- NewsFeed and creating a story -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">


        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="panel panel-default widget" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Recent Stories</h3>
                        <span class="label label-info">
                            78</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="each in story.stories | reverse" >
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="mic-info">
                                                     {{ each.createdAt | date:'MMM d, yyyy' }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="comment-text">
                                                <a href="/{{ story._id }}"><h4>{{ each.content }}</h4></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>



            <div class="col-md-3">


            </div>
```

Comment: You could use local storage maybe

Comment: Could you show some example, so that I could accept your answer

Comment: Are you sure the loading time comes from the server request, and not the DOM rendering time? You should log each step (`console.time`and `console.timeEnd` in Chrome). Since the list is pretty long, it could totally be that it takes time to Angular to create all the nodes of your list, hence it is not a "caching" or whatever issue, but an optimization issue.

Comment: I believe it is DOM rendering time, hence the problem is with angular. What would you do If you were me to optimize this site? to make it load instantly?

Comment: You could do many minor optimizations: reduce the watchers in your ng-repeat (bindonce), but the most visible would probably to set up "infinite" scrolling: instead of displaying all items, display only like 20 and load more as the user scrolls. You can implement your own directive (have a look at `limitTo` for `ng-repeat`) or find something on google (how about http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, basically the problem is not about whether I limit it or not, even if you go to a single page with a single content , it will still loads up. So what do you think about that? if you want to see the open source tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading problem you see is that the data is fetched after the view has been created. You can delay the loading of the view by using the `resolve` property of the route:

```
.when('/allStories', {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/allStories.html',
    controller: 'AllStoryController',
    controllerAs: 'story',
    resolve: {
        stories: function(Story) {
            return Story.allStories();
        }
    }
})
```

Angular will delay the loading of the view until all resolve properties have been resolved. You then inject the property into the controller:

```
.controller('AllStoryController', function(socketio, stories) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.stories = stories.data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, could we go to chat?

Comment: Basically I couldn't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use local storage. suited module - [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

The data is kept aslong you or the client user clean the data,

Usage is easily:

`bower install angular-local-storage --save`

```
 var storyService = angular.module('storyService', ['LocalStorageModule']);
```

In a controller:

```
storyService.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService', 
                                     function($scope, localStorageService) {
       localStorageService.set(key, val); //return boolean
       localStorageService.get(key); // returl val

}]);
```

Match this usage to your scenario (for example - put the stories array on and just append updates to it)